# I don't understand the use of 'are come'

Tags: grammar

I don't understand the use of **are come** in the following sentence. Please explain it to me. The sentence is from *Pride and Prejudice* by Jane Austen.

> I am glad you **are come** back, Lizzy.

Comment: English has changed a bit over the past couple hundred years.  This is an old-fashioned *present perfect* construction, similar to "*have* come back".

Comment: We still use **you are returned** (and, of course, **you are back**) to mean that **you have come back** but the expression might reflect the age of the speaker.

Comment: Remember me when I am gone away, 
Gone far away into the silent land;
When you can no more hold me by the hand,
Nor I half turn to go, yet turning stay.

Answer (score 1):

"are come" is an older form. It means "have come". *I am glad you have come back, Lizzy.*